# OSGi, Amdatu REST example doesn't work

Tags: rest, jax-rs, osgi, apache-wink, amdatu

I am trying to run an **Amdatu REST example**, I have created a project with **bndtools**, then I have used the **amdatu bootstrap** to add dependencies both the project itself and to the run descriptor.

I have annotated my class with **@Path and @Component(provides = Object.class)**.

When I execute the run descriptor, there is no error in the cmd but when I open the url (eg: http://127.0.0.1:8080/test) it gives me **404 error**:

> HTTP ERROR: 404
>
> Problem accessing /test. Reason:
>
> ```
> Not Found Powered by Jetty://
> ```

below is output when I start the run descriptor:

```
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] : Logging to org.ops4j.pax.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLogger@4f9a3314 via org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] : Logging initialized @4293ms Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@275710fc added {qtp1663619914{STOPPED,8<=0<=200,i=0,q=0},AUTO} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@275710fc added {HashLoginService[OSGi HTTP Service Realm],AUTO} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection@48524010[o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4b168fa9{/,null,null}] added {o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4b168fa9{/,null,null},AUTO} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler@45dd4eda added {org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@60611244,AUTO} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4b168fa9{/,null,null} added {org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler@45dd4eda,AUTO} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler@45dd4eda added {org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@4387b79e,AUTO} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@60611244 added {org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.EventDispatcher@6e75aa0d,UNMANAGED} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@4387b79e added {org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet-197d671@cec6b31a==org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet,-1,true,AUTO} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@4387b79e added {[/*]=>org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet-197d671,POJO} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@275710fc added {org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection@48524010[o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4b168fa9{/,null,null}],AUTO} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : starting org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@275710fc Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server] : jetty-9.2.12.v20150709 Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler] : starting org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@275710fc Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : starting qtp1663619914{STOPPED,8<=0<=200,i=0,q=0} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : STARTED @4564ms qtp1663619914{STARTED,8<=8<=200,i=4,q=0} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : starting HashLoginService[OSGi HTTP Service Realm] Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService] : doStart: Starting new PropertyUserStore. PropertiesFile: null refreshInterval: 0 Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : starting org.eclipse.jetty.security.PropertyUserStore@79efed2d Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : STARTED @4573ms org.eclipse.jetty.security.PropertyUserStore@79efed2d Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : STARTED @4573ms HashLoginService[OSGi HTTP Service Realm] Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : starting org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection@48524010[o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4b168fa9{/,null,null}] Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection] : ->[{o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4b168fa9{/,null,null},[o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4b168fa9{/,null,null}]}] Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler] : starting org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection@48524010[o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4b168fa9{/,null,null}] Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : starting o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4b168fa9{/,null,null} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler] : starting o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4b168fa9{/,null,STARTING} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : starting org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler@45dd4eda Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler] : starting org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler@45dd4eda Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : starting org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@60611244 Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@60611244 added {org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@18ce0030,MANAGED} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : starting org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionIdManager@63a65a25 Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : STARTED @4610ms org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionIdManager@63a65a25 Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@275710fc added {org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionIdManager@63a65a25,MANAGED} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@60611244 added {org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionIdManager@63a65a25,UNMANAGED} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : starting org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@18ce0030 Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : STARTED @4615ms org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@18ce0030 Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : STARTED @4621ms org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@60611244 Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : starting org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@4387b79e Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler] : Chose path=/* mapped to servlet=org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet-197d671 from default=false Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler] : filterNameMap={} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler] : pathFilters=null Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler] : servletFilterMap=null Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler] : servletPathMap={/*=org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet-197d671@cec6b31a==org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet,-1,true} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler] : servletNameMap={org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet-197d671=org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet-197d671@cec6b31a==org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet,-1,true} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler] : Adding Default404Servlet to org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@4387b79e Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@4387b79e added {org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Default404Servlet-5276e6b0@94c0e60f==org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Default404Servlet,-1,false,AUTO} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@4387b79e added {[/]=>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Default404Servlet-5276e6b0,POJO} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler] : Chose path=/* mapped to servlet=org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet-197d671 from default=false Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler] : Chose path=/ mapped to servlet=org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Default404Servlet-5276e6b0 from default=false Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler] : filterNameMap={} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler] : pathFilters=null Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler] : servletFilterMap=null Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler] : servletPathMap={/*=org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet-197d671@cec6b31a==org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet,-1,true, /=org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Default404Servlet-5276e6b0@94c0e60f==org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Default404Servlet,-1,false} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler] : servletNameMap={org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet-197d671=org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet-197d671@cec6b31a==org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet,-1,true, org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Default404Servlet-5276e6b0=org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Default404Servlet-5276e6b0@94c0e60f==org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Default404Servlet,-1,false} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler] : starting org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@4387b79e Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : STARTED @4639ms org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@4387b79e Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : STARTED @4639ms org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler@45dd4eda Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : starting org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet-197d671@cec6b31a==org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet,-1,true Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : STARTED @4648ms org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet-197d671@cec6b31a==org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet,-1,true Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder] : Servlet.init org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet@48fa0f47 for org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet-197d671 Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : starting org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Default404Servlet-5276e6b0@94c0e60f==org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Default404Servlet,-1,false Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : STARTED @4715ms org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Default404Servlet-5276e6b0@94c0e60f==org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Default404Servlet,-1,false Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler] : Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4b168fa9{/,null,AVAILABLE} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : STARTED @4717ms o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4b168fa9{/,null,AVAILABLE} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : STARTED @4718ms org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection@48524010[o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4b168fa9{/,null,AVAILABLE}] Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server] : Started @4719ms Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : STARTED @4720ms org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@275710fc Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : HttpConnectionFactory@3ba9ad43{HTTP/1.1} added {HttpConfiguration@49d904ec{32768/8192,8192/8192,https://:0,[]},POJO} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : ServerConnector@29626d54{null}{0.0.0.0:0} added {org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@275710fc,UNMANAGED} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : ServerConnector@29626d54{null}{0.0.0.0:0} added {qtp1663619914{STARTED,8<=8<=200,i=8,q=0},UNMANAGED} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : ServerConnector@29626d54{null}{0.0.0.0:0} added {org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@72a7c7e0,AUTO} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : ServerConnector@29626d54{null}{0.0.0.0:0} added {org.eclipse.jetty.io.ArrayByteBufferPool@5a63f509,POJO} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : ServerConnector@29626d54{null}{0.0.0.0:0} added {HttpConnectionFactory@3ba9ad43{HTTP/1.1},AUTO} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : ServerConnector@29626d54{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:0} added {org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector$ServerConnectorManager@10e41621,MANAGED} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@275710fc added {ServerConnector@29626d54{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080},UNMANAGED} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : starting ServerConnector@29626d54{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : ServerConnector@29626d54{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080} added {sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080],POJO} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : starting org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@72a7c7e0 Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : STARTED @4780ms org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@72a7c7e0 Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : starting HttpConnectionFactory@3ba9ad43{HTTP/1.1} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : STARTED @4781ms HttpConnectionFactory@3ba9ad43{HTTP/1.1} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : starting org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector$ServerConnectorManager@10e41621 Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : starting org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@9353778 keys=-1 selected=-1 Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : STARTED @5053ms org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@9353778 keys=0 selected=0 Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : starting org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@5ffead27 keys=-1 selected=-1 Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager] : Starting Thread[qtp1663619914-27-selector-ServerConnectorManager@10e41621/0,5,main] on org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@9353778 keys=0 selected=0 Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager] : Selector loop waiting on select Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : STARTED @5062ms org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@5ffead27 keys=0 selected=0 Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : STARTED @5063ms org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector$ServerConnectorManager@10e41621 Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager] : Starting Thread[qtp1663619914-24-selector-ServerConnectorManager@10e41621/1,5,main] on org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@5ffead27 keys=0 selected=0 Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager] : [org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle] : ServerConnector@29626d54{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080} added {acceptor-0@359f7cdf,POJO} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
Selector loop waiting on select Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector] : Started ServerConnector@29626d54{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] : STARTED @5068ms ServerConnector@29626d54{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080} Ignored FQCN: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[INFO] Started Jetty 9.2.12.v20150709 at port(s) HTTP:8080 on context path /
[INFO] Detected extended HttpService. Filters enabled.
[INFO] Http service whiteboard started
[WARNING] Deprecation warning: Filter registered through Apache Felix whiteboard service: [javax.servlet.Filter]. Please change your code to the OSGi Http Whiteboard Service.
[DEBUG] Reusing context with id []
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api[org.ops4j.pax.logging.internal.Activator] : Enabling SLF4J API support.
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api[org.ops4j.pax.logging.internal.Activator] : Enabling Jakarta Commons Logging API support.
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api[org.ops4j.pax.logging.internal.Activator] : Enabling Log4J API support.
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api[org.ops4j.pax.logging.internal.Activator] : Enabling Avalon Logger API support.
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api[org.ops4j.pax.logging.internal.Activator] : Enabling JULI Logger API support.
[FelixDispatchQueue] DEBUG org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service - BundleEvent STARTED - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service
[main] DEBUG org.apache.felix.gogo.command - ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.apache.felix.gogo.command.Basic] - org.apache.felix.gogo.command
[main] DEBUG org.apache.felix.gogo.command - ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.apache.felix.gogo.command.Inspect] - org.apache.felix.gogo.command
[main] DEBUG org.apache.felix.gogo.command - ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.apache.felix.gogo.command.Files] - org.apache.felix.gogo.command
[main] DEBUG org.apache.felix.gogo.command - ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.apache.felix.gogo.command.OBR] - org.apache.felix.gogo.command
[FelixDispatchQueue] DEBUG org.apache.felix.gogo.command - BundleEvent STARTED - org.apache.felix.gogo.command
[main] DEBUG org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime - ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.apache.felix.service.threadio.ThreadIO] - org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime
[main] DEBUG org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime - ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.apache.felix.service.command.CommandProcessor] - org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime
[FelixDispatchQueue] DEBUG org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime - BundleEvent STARTED - org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime
[main] DEBUG org.apache.felix.gogo.shell - ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.apache.felix.service.command.Converter] - org.apache.felix.gogo.shell
[main] DEBUG org.apache.felix.gogo.shell - ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Builtin] - org.apache.felix.gogo.shell
[main] DEBUG org.apache.felix.gogo.shell - ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Procedural] - org.apache.felix.gogo.shell
[main] DEBUG org.apache.felix.gogo.shell - ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Posix] - org.apache.felix.gogo.shell
[main] DEBUG org.apache.felix.gogo.shell - ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Telnet] - org.apache.felix.gogo.shell
[main] DEBUG org.apache.felix.gogo.shell - ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Shell] - org.apache.felix.gogo.shell
[FelixDispatchQueue] DEBUG org.apache.felix.gogo.shell - BundleEvent STARTED - org.apache.felix.gogo.shell
[main] DEBUG org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.shell - ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.apache.felix.dm.shell.DMCommand] - org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.shell
[FelixDispatchQueue] DEBUG org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.shell - BundleEvent STARTED - org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.shell
[main] DEBUG org.apache.felix.framework - ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [java.lang.Object, aQute.launcher.Launcher] - org.apache.felix.framework
____________________________
Welcome to Apache Felix Gogo

g!
```

executing **lb** gives following output:

```
g! lb
START LEVEL 1
   ID|State      |Level|Name
    0|Active     |    0|System Bundle (5.2.0)
    1|Active     |    1|abc.xyz.rest.test (0.0.0)
    2|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Http Jetty (3.1.0)
    3|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Http API (3.0.0)
    4|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Servlet API (1.1.2)
    5|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Http Whiteboard (3.0.0)
    6|Active     |    1|org.amdatu.web.rest.jaxrs (1.0.9)
    7|Active     |    1|org.amdatu.web.rest.wink (2.0.4)
    8|Active     |    1|org.amdatu.web.rest.doc (1.2.3)
    9|Active     |    1|Jackson-annotations (2.6.3)
   10|Active     |    1|Jackson-core (2.6.3)
   11|Active     |    1|jackson-databind (2.6.3)
   12|Active     |    1|Jackson-JAXRS-base (2.6.3)
   13|Active     |    1|Jackson-JAXRS-JSON (2.6.3)
   14|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Dependency Manager (4.3.0)
   15|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Dependency Manager Runtime (4.0.3)
   16|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Metatype Service (1.1.2)
   17|Active     |    1|Apache Felix EventAdmin (1.4.4)
   18|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Configuration Admin Service (1.8.8)
   19|Active     |    1|OPS4J Pax Logging - API (1.7.0)
   20|Active     |    1|OPS4J Pax Logging - Service (1.7.0)
   21|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.14.0)
   22|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.16.2)
   23|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.10.0)
   24|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Dependency Manager Shell (4.0.4)
```

executing **dm** gives me below output:

```
g! dm
[1] abc.xyz.rest.test
 [6] java.lang.Object registered
[7] org.amdatu.web.rest.wink
 [0] org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder(OSGi) registered
    org.osgi.service.log.LogService service optional available
 [1] org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService(service.pid=org.amdatu.web.rest.wink) registered
    java.lang.Object (objectClass=*) service optional available
    org.osgi.service.log.LogService service optional available
 [2] org.amdatu.web.rest.jaxrs.JaxRsSpi registered
 [3] javax.servlet.Filter(service.ranking=-10,pattern=/.*) registered
    org.osgi.service.log.LogService service optional available
 [4] javax.ws.rs.core.Application registered
    org.osgi.service.log.LogService service optional available
[15] org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.runtime
 [5] org.apache.felix.dm.runtime.DependencyManagerRuntime registered
    active (DependencyManager-Component=*) bundle optional available
    org.osgi.service.packageadmin.PackageAdmin service required available
    org.osgi.service.log.LogService service optional available
```

executing **dm notavail** gives me no output.

any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me after changing the version of **org.amdatu.web.rest.wink** from **2.0.4** to **2.0.3**

Answer (score 0):

**I FOUND THE SOLUTION**

I started over and created a new workspace, installed **Amdatu Eclipse Plugin** using **Eclipse marketplace**, 
and then used the **Amdatu Configuration** when creating **cnf** project.

This solved my problem.